# Counter--; Help me understand

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, counter

Application, have a TextBlock and two Buttons, the text is displayed TextBlock by clicking on the button (the text of the Q.txt is read line by line, over a hundred lines):

```
public class QWork
{
   public static int counter = 0;

   public static string GetQ()
    {
        var qFile = new List<string>();

        string pathFile = "Q.txt";
        Uri uri = new Uri(pathFile, UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream))
        {
            string line = "";
            while (line != null)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                    qFile.Add(line);  // Add to list
            }
            return qFile[counter];
        }
    }
}
```

Buttons event handler:

```
    private void RightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//Next text
    {
        qTextBlock.Text = QWork.GetQ();
        QWork.counter++;
    }

    private void LeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//Previous text
    {
        qTextBlock.Text = QWork.GetQ();
        QWork.counter --;
    }
```

Problem:
When I click LeftButton, a first still shows the following line, but only after previous.
Tell me please, how can I fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "a first still shows the following line". Did you really mean to increment/decrement the counter *before* fetching the text though? (As an aside, reading the whole file on each button click seems like an awful idea to me.)

Comment: `qFile[counter];` in case would give you first line for `counter = 0` , is that what you mean ?

Comment: You keep on loading the list, and then you set the counter, only load the list once at start up, and get the Q by index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```
int counter = 0;
List<string> qs = null;

private void LoadQs()
{
    qs = new List<string>();
    qs.Add("aaa");
    qs.Add("bbb");
    qs.Add("ccc");
}

private string GetQ(bool increase)
{
    if (increase)
        counter++;
    else
        counter--;

    if (counter >= qs.Count)
        counter = 0;
    else if (counter <= 0)
        counter = qs.Count;

    string q = qs[counter];

    return q;
}
```